# firebase.update() causing nodejs server to crash: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, firebase

I am trying to update a firebase location from inside my server.js file in nodejs. Using the `.update()` from the firebase api causes the app to crash and throw and error "Can't set headers after they are sent". If I comment out the code updating the firebase location there is no error. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Code causing the error:

```
app.post('/updateFire', function(req,res){
    var updateInfo = req.body;
    console.log(updateInfo);
    var onComplete = function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Synchronization failed');
        } else {
            console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
            res.json('done');
        }
    };
    ref.update({points:updateInfo.points,totalAmount:updateInfo.totalAmount}, onComplete);
});
```

But if you take that code out and do a simple response back to the client, it does not throw error:

```
app.post('/updateFire', function(req,res){
    var updateInfo = req.body;
    console.log(updateInfo);
    res.json('done');
});
```

What is it about the firebase `.update()` that causes the crash?

**UPDATE ERROR IN CONSOLE FROM FIREBASE**

I guess the console was outputting an error from firebase:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:695:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:146:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:235:15)
    at /Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/app.js:36:13
    at /Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:49:642
    at Ab (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:46:165)
    at wb (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:22:216)
    at xb (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:21:1260)
    at Qh.g.update (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:204:471) 
/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-node.js:46
ion(){P("Exception was thrown by user callback.",b.stack||"");throw b;},Math.f
```

**STACK TRACE ERROR:**

```
stack trace:  Error
    at /Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/app.js:56:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at next (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at /Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at /Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603:15
    at next (/Users/chaselester/Sites/Development/chore-tracker/chore-angular/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:14)
```

Comment: It's an async problem, the code is trying to do something after the response has been sent.

Comment: Are you sure that the first code block is all of your actual code for that `app.post()` request handler?  Because the type of error you're getting comes from mishandling async responses, but I don't see that type of fault in the code you've disclosed.

Comment: Yes, that is everything in the app.post() request

Comment: Then, I think the error you see is actually coming from some other piece of code.  I don't see how this code by itself can cause that error.

Comment: That is why I am confused about it. If I remove it, the error does not persist.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `onComplete` argument from the `.update()` call?  I know you won't have a `res.json()` call to finish the request, but I'd like to know what happens when you remove just that and still do the `update()`.  Also, is the `app.post()` being triggered by an ajax call or by a plain HTML form post?

Comment: The error is the same

Comment: Then, apparently you have a screwed up database somehow and the error is coming from your database code.

Comment: The other thing is, it updates the firebase location. The app just crashes right after it does so. But on refresh of the app, the updated data shows up in the UI

Comment: Do you have a stack trace with this error?  Can you post that?

Comment: I posted an update with a stacktrace firebase was sending out

Comment: My guess is that you have some sort of callback or event handler set up to get notified of something in your database and you're attempting to send a response or set a header in that callback (which is causing this problem).  This may be a Firebase `.on()` event handler that you wanted in place for some other action and didn't know would be triggered with this update.

Comment: If you are receiving the same error after you remove res.json(); from the callback, then you will need to post more code/fiddle so that we could help you further.

Comment: Its not the removal of the res.json() that it still throws the error. Its when I add the firebase.update() when it throws the error. I can remove that and have no issue. Client can make the call to the server with the .post, and res.json() works fine, until I add the firebase .update()

Comment: @Chipe I'm getting a similar error (update causing a nodejs to crash). Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience(same error), you must reading data from Firebase with .on('value',fn) method somewhere in your code. You should change it to .once('value',fn). Because .on('value',fn) method turns you back when you .update() data on Firebase and probably tries to res.send({}) again. This is why you are getting 'Can't set headers after they are sent' error.